# Automate Retry on Expired Auth Token in JavaScript SDK

Tags: node.js, authentication, oop, sdk, refresh-token

#### The Scenario

A Node.js app uses some third-party SDK that makes authorized calls to an API. The authorization mechanism is an access token to be passed alongside the call, and --- if the token has expired -- a response sent to the client code 401.

#### What I Would Like to Know

How can augment this SDK so that calls containing an expired token automatically retry the original request, after a valid access taken is returned?

#### In Other Words,

I'm surprised that the SDK doesn't do this by default. It has methods to get and set tokens. If an access token has been set, it places that in the request, but doesn't handle responses. My code, therefore, is left checking each failed request for 401, and manually fetching, then updating tokens, and -- then -- retrying the original call.

#### DRY

is what this ain't. While I am displeased the SDK doesn't automate this process, I would not be surprised to learn that such a pattern is common. Have backend Node.js developers encountered something along these lines, and -- if so -- how did you approach a solution?

#### Finally

Thank you.

*PS. I tried extending the SDK as a subclass, and re-casting methods that call the API in a thunk'd iteration. I did not get very far.*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.